# Is this a bug in swift or my code is not correct(uialertcontroller)?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

In this case I am using a uialertcontroller to inform user chose save , discard or cancel changes . but after the message appearing and before disappearing  , the other code after that(makeNewDocument()) is executed.
I am not sure is there a solution?

```
 @objc func deleteToNew(_ notification: Notification) {
    if AppDelegate.DocInEditing{
        let dialogMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Save changes?", message: "This file belongs to \(UserManager.shared.firstname)  \(UserManager.shared.lastname). Do you want to save changes?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
                    let Yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes save", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "saveChanges"), object: nil)
                        
                    })
                    let No = UIAlertAction(title: "No Discard changes", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                    
                    })
                        
                    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) -> Void in
                    return
                    }
                    dialogMessage.addAction(Yes)
                    dialogMessage.addAction(No)
                    dialogMessage.addAction(cancel)
            present(dialogMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
    }

    makeNewDocument()
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't stop executing when you display the alert. The alert is shown and when the user selects an action, the code associated with that action runs,  the in the mean time the rest of your code runs. You probably want to `makeNewDocument` in the closure for "yes"

Comment: ... and also into after the "save" notification call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a bug in swift

No

> or my code is not correct(uialertcontroller)?

Yes

---

The alert controller and its actions work asynchronously, to run something on completion there is the `completion` parameter. Call it there

```
present(dialogMessage, animated: true, completion: makeNewDocument)
```

Or if you want to call `makeNewDocument` only in one of the actions, move the line into the action body

```
let yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes save", style: .default, handler: { action in
             NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "saveChanges"), object: nil)
             self.makeNewDocument()                        
          })
```

---

Side note:

It's highly recommended to create `Notification.Name` constants only in an extension to take advantage of the safety of those constants

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let saveChanges = Notification.Name(rawValue: "saveChanges")
}
```

and use it

```
let yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes save", style: .default, handler: { action in
             NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .saveChanges, object: nil)
             self.makeNewDocument()                        
          })
```

Comment: thank you for side note.
but at the main problem I want not to execute "makeNewDocument" when cancel is selected.

Comment: Then pass `nil` in `completion` and use the second suggestion.